# deck.gl get color of TripsLayer

Tags: javascript, json, web, deck.gl, getcolor

```js
layers.push(new TripsLayer({
        id: 'trips',
        data: trips,
        getPath: (d: Trip) => d.segments.map((p: Waypoint) => p.coordinates),
        getTimestamps: (d: Trip) => d.segments.map((p: Waypoint) => p.timestamp),
        getColor: (d: Trip) => d.segments.map((p: Waypoint) => p.color),//this.getColor,
        opacity: 0.3,
        widthMinPixels: 5,
        trailLength,
        currentTime
```

I only have one trip to show by Deck.gl, and I want to make every coordinate of trip have different colors. But the color don't change as the change of location and time, and it's usually black. 
I  set the property of color in the 'trips.json', it can be listed as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. I use a function to set the color, it seems it only runs once.
Maybe is because `getcolor` is a "render option" and not a "data accessor".
From:
https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/trips-layer